# Faild to create MultiTargetObserver: DATABASE_LOAD_ERROR

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia, vuforia-cloud-recognition

I'm using unity as library in react native. So when i open camera, getting this issue mention below. It's working when i use to make build from unity. But its not working when i use to make build from react native.

Exception in callback: Failed to create MultiTargetObserver: DATABASE_LOAD_ERROR

Vuforia.Utility.ExtensionMethods.DelegateHelper:InvokeDelegate(Delegate, Object[])

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone faces the same issue in future here is our solution how we(We because the guy asked the question and I are working together on same project) fixed it.

So in our case we were doing everything from this official link : https://library.vuforia.com/unity-extension/using-vuforia-engine-unity-library-uaal by vuforia except doing one mistake when Dragging "Vuforia" Folder from Unity Generated XCode Project to our Native iOS project that we were copying and then pasting it from finder and that was not working.

Instead you have to do is to drag and drop the Vuforia Folder from Unity Xcode project to Your Native project [Drag This Vuforia Folder form Unity to Native which Contains Data Base files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R41z0.png)

and then you will see a Pop up and choose options as shown in this [Add to Target will Show Your Native Project Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olFGX.png)

And You are Done. This should fix the issue saying "Exception in callback: Failed to create MultiTargetObserver: DATABASE_LOAD_ERROR" or "Exception in callback: Failed to create ImageTargetObserver: DATABASE_LOAD_ERROR"